# Should file names contain multiple periods?

Tags: filesystems, file-management, file-sharing

I often name files using a convention such that I incorporate a version number at the end, similar to `Some Deliverable - v0.1.docx`. Sometimes when colleagues make changes and send back revised versions they will update that version number, but they will also replace the extra period with a space, such as `Some Deliverable - v0 2.docx`.

This happens often enough, with a wide enough variety of colleagues, that I wonder: Is there still a danger in naming a file with multiple periods? Are my colleagues being overly cautious or taking valid precautions? And if it is a valid precaution, under what circumstances would a file with multiple periods cause problems?

If this is a holdover from pre-Windows 95 days or something then I'm not worried, but if this is something that, for example, causes problems when sharing a file with a Mac user – or an iPad user? – or a Linux user then I'll change my ways and stick to one period in a file name, before the extension.

Comment: I never had any problems in using multiple dots in file names. Not under GNU/linux (ext2 fs), nor on FreeBSD, nor on windows (FAT32 and NTFS). Accessing such files via a samba network always worked. I strongly *suspect* that there is no problem.

Comment: Especially considering that Linux and OS X users have dealt with files named `something-v1.23.4-something.tar.gz.sig` for *years* without any troubles...

Comment: I agree that there is no problem per se, but if I had my druthers, I would make all users use keyboards with nothing but the letters of the alphabet and a period. Not even a space bar or a shift key.

Comment: i.dont.even.know.if.youre.serious.or.trolling.mr.ebgreen...

Comment: I've seen warnings about files having multiple extensions, but I don't remember if that was Windows or a browser or what. I haven't used any version of Windows newer than XP on a daily basis, so I don't know if there's something in the additional security layers of Vista/7 that might be complaining. As @grawity said, Linux and OS X users have had multiple periods in their files for years.

Comment: Meh...an impossible dream I know. Not intended to be a troll. Just years of writing regexes and string parsing routines that are more complex than they would be if users were restricted to my ideal keyboard. I would of course get a full keyboard as per the double standard that is the perogative of IT professionals everywhere...

Comment: The multiple extensions warning was for windows.  With the default windows [explorer] configuration "some_virus.jpg.exe" would show up as a seemlingly harmless picture file named "some_virus.jpg".

Comment: @Hennes, except that with that default configuration, the ".jpg" extension shouldn't have been visible, so when you see it, it's a sign that it's not the *real* extension.

Comment: Aye. Should have. All the people who failed to notice that and messed up their computers came running to me (well, to IT) to fix their computers.  Many of them bright enough to have realized something was odd if only one file showed an extension.

Comment: @Hennes: It *could* be that some didn't notice this because they don't know whether their mail program honors the "hide extension" setting or not when listing attachments.

Comment: @Hennes Why then would you name such a file `some_virus.jpg.exe` instead of just `some_virus.exe` so it would show up to the user as `some_virus`, without a tell-tale extension that shouldn't be visible?

Comment: Good question. But it *was* done a lot. So there probably was a stronger mental step 'oh, harmless picture' than a 'Huh, that is weird. I need to look closer at this'.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

#### Theory

Since [long filenames](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_filename) and [VFAT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_Allocation_Table#VFAT) exist, filenames with two periods in them are perfectly valid in Windows.

As far as the modern file system is concerned, there's no such thing as an extension. A period is a character like any else. The GUI treats everything that follows the *last* period as the file's extension.

Linux always behaved this way.

#### Practice

[SharePoint](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-us/sharepointgeneral/thread/08c1a5f5-cc15-446e-be11-9c48a906dd9f), [ProFTP](https://forums.proftpd.org/smf/index.php?topic=4508.0), [TransferText](http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/filename-two-dot-cant-work-transfertext-t1139194.html), [Symphony](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/symfony2/5hWUexCYmkU), [KVR Audio](http://www.kvraudio.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=47464) and [servedir](https://github.com/remy/servedir/issues/13) all have or had some problem with multiple periods in filenames.

However, not handling multiple periods properly is ultimately a bug. It's easy to make a mistake when spitting up a filename in its basename and extension, but the problem is the program, not the filename.

Comment: In a way, there *is* such a thing as an extension, and it has very similar treatment in both Windows and Unix – in particular, it is widely used in GUIs (practically every Linux GUI file manager), mainly to decide which file type and icon to show, while avoiding expensive "magic number" tests; however, practically irrelevant in CLIs where the user chooses the program themselves. Yes, even on Windows, the .exe extension is irrelevant in command line; you can name a file `notepad.jpg` and it will still run.

Comment: However, since introduction of LFNs, the extension is *not* separate from the file name anymore – even on Windows, a period is a character like any else.

Comment: @grawity: That's more or less what I wanted to write (although it didn't come out as well): Extensions became a simple convention in Windows, i.e, they're not part of the file system anymore. The `notepad.jpg` is interesting.

Comment: For what it's worth, windows compiled executeables to this day still have the 5A 4D (MZ) magic number which is the legacy of Mark Zbikowski who created the format.

Comment: Hmm. SharePoint or one of the other products mentioned here might very well be the culprit; if colleagues have wanted to upload files and had troubles from multiple periods it might be why they're wary of using them. It may be a bug, but the net result is that we still have to work around it...

Comment: Just to add to your list of Windows applications with problems with multiple-period-file names, Microsoft Access will not import files with more than one "." (fails with a FILE_NOT_FOUND).

Answer (score 4):

Multiple dots have not been a problem on Windows since Windows 95, and on other operating systems for even longer.

(I never use periods because I hate adding quotation marks `""` in terminal afterwards. But that's not the point of your question.)

But multiple dots in filename could cause problems in some cases, mostly with webapps and upload feature (obviously because of incorrect implementation of this feature).

Comment: In what terminal do you have to add quotation marks around filenames with (multiple) periods?

Comment: It is a problem if you use libraries to get file extensions. They only ever return last occurrence

Answer (score 2):

I just discovered an issue under Windows Corporate XP SP3 like this.  Basically I can have as many periods as I like, as long as the file name does not *start* with a period.

Example:

```
.ILS.files.in.use.DFS.20140515.0700.csv
```

(File copied from Unix FS to windows, this is a legit file name under Unix I believe)

When I try to rename this file, if I leave the initial period in the operation, it fails with the error message "You must type a file name."

Removing the initial period, and adding the datestamp with period separators, this shows you can have as many periods as you like (subject to other name restrictions) and is a valid Windows file name:

```
ILS.files.in.use.DFS.2014.05.15.0700.csv
```

Comment: That’s just a restriction (well, bug IMHO) with Windows Explorer. Even Command Prompt (`ren` command) can handle file names starting with a period.